# I want to make an API in angular and JAX-RS to receive an object as Hashmap instead of mapping every time into a class

Tags: java, angular, hashmap, promise, jax-rs

I have a method which is saving a person object into DB using JAX-RS.
In Angular I have a method to make post request to save a person object      {"name: "xyz", "id": 123}.
    Instead of mapping Person object into Person class in JAX-RS I want convert object into Hashmap. In Angular I want a method like.

```
myhttpRequest("POST",savePerson, '{"name: "xyz, "id": 123}').then(
    function(response) {
        //Action in success response
    }, function() {
        //Action in failure response
    });
```

In JAX-RS I want to implement this kind of structure

```
PersonManager pm = new PersonManager();

@POST
@Path("/create")
@Consumes(value = { "text/plain" })
@Produces(value = { "application/json" })
public Response receivePerson(String Str) {
    Hashmap hs = convertStringToHashmap(Str);
    String MethodName = hs.get("MethodName");
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(pm.class.getMethod("MethodName").invoke(hs)).build();
}

// In PersonManager class savePerson() method is defined
savePerson(Hashmap hs){
    String Name = hs.get("name");
    int id = hs.get("id");
    //saving into db
}
```

I need help to implement myhttpRequest() method in Angular which will return promise object and for convertStringToHashmap which will convert received object into Hashmap.

Comment: You don't need to do any conversion if you're using Jackson. You can do `public Response receivePerson(Map<String, Object> json)`, if you send JSON, not plain text that looks like JSON.

Comment: Thank you.I got my answer in this link using Jackson.
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-map-to-from-json-jackson/